# django 4 recent issue

Tags: python, django, django-4.0

Django has recently released a new version and I'm trying to work with it.
But the problem that I have is that one I say `pip install Django no matter in the cmd or visual studio's cmd, it installs Django 4.0, but once I put the file in the code editor (it is vs code), it changes to Django 3.0 and I was shocked once I saw that even in` pip freeze` it is changed!
I would be so glad if you can help me with this problem

Comment: You can try typing the version that you want. `pip install django==4.0.0`

Comment: Actually I did but there was no changes

Comment: try creating your virtual environment and doing pip install there